# Problem with PostgreSQL functions and Apache ANT

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, ant, delimiter, build.xml

I have a build.xml file like this:

```
...
<target name="CreateStoredProcedures"> 
    <sql 
        driver="${sql.driver}" 
        url="${sql.db}"
        userid="${sql.user}" 
        password="${sql.pwd}" 
        autocommit="true"
        classpath="${classpath}"
        delimiter = "$$"
        > 
        <connectionProperty name="useSSL" value="false" />
        <path>
            <fileset dir=".">
                <include name= "4*.sql"/>
            </fileset>
        </path>  
    </sql> 
</target> 
...
```

and this SQL code:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS "sp_create_usuario";
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "sp_create_usuario"(
    "in_nombre" VARCHAR(45) , 
    "in_tipo" tipo 
)
RETURNS TABLE (last_id INT8) AS $$

INSERT INTO "usuario"
(
    "nombre", 
    "tipo"
)
VALUES
(
    "in_nombre", 
    "in_tipo"
) RETURNING "id";

$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

so, when i run build.xml with ANT, i get error like "syntax error at the end of the entry" or "syntax error near something ..." depending on where, and what I put in the delimiters.

I've done this with MySQL but i cant with PostgreSQL :(

How can I do to execute stored procedures with ant and postgres?

Comment: DataType "tipo" is already created

Comment: I have never used Ant with the sql tag, but `delimiter = "$$"` looks wrong. That will split the statements on the `$$` which in fact is the alternate quoting character. Usually the safest thing is to not let tools like that split the statements and only put one SQL statement at a time into a `sql` task (and tell it to **not** split on `;` as well)

Comment: apparently Ant has a default delimiter, so I put  delimiter = "//"  and change the $$ for $body$ in sql code